# What does "burning under your nails" mean?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

The context that I have encountered is: "Ask anything else that burns under your nails".

For the above case, does it imply ANY question in my mind or just the ones that bugs me or does it mean simply "don't be shy"?

Comment: It didn't sound entirely like a native english saying and i've seen one claim online that it is German in origin. I'd certainly interpret it a being about things that. if you over a period rather than fleeting concerns, but there may be more info if anyone can investigate a german version. https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/reference-vs-value-types-in-swift-part-2-2/6708

Comment: The uses I've seen are closer to "the ones that bug you", the ones that are always on your mind, and thus the ones burning under your nails.

Comment: It is German in origin--its meaning is that it's something you find very urgent, like finishing a paper on time.  It's not only spoken German but appears in written German as early as the 16th century. Auf den Nägeln brennen, for which there's a German Wikipedia page.